# How to execute shell commands as root in Java

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder

I'm working on a cross-platform installation utility written in Java. I would like to be able to execute shell commands, for example "apt-get ..." on Linux. I'm using the ProcessBuilder API for this purpose.

Unfortunately, some commands require root privileges. I would like to execute the following shell command as root:

bash -c apt-get install -y [some package]

If I try to add "sudo" before "apt-get" nothing works because there is no terminal "sudo" can get the password from.

What should I do in order to ask the user for a password and then execute the above mentioned shell command?

A short code snippet would be very appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Max

Comment: Run the installer with root privileges is that is what is required.

Comment: I'm planning to use this installer from within Java Web Start. It's not a good idea to gain JavaWS too much privileges. Moreover, I would like to execute root commands only if required. My installer checks first if any installation is necessary or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run `gksudo <your command>` but this ties your application to a certain UI, e.g. gnome, kde, etc.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Binding to UI is not an issue to me because my project is targeting primarily graphical environments.

Comment: @user1815381: We usually accept answers if they help. I hope you do the same, it is has helped. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry! I didn't know that. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You could write all the the root-tasks to a scriptfile and ask the user to execute it with root privileges. I know this sounds clumsy, but its done that way by quite a lot of "enterprise level" software vendors (e.g. the (Java-) installer of the Oracle RDBMS at least up to 11g).